# Error after Updating Craft

Tags: error-message, updating

After submitting the last Craft Update over the CP i got the following error:

Warning: require(/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/craft on line 21

Warning: require(/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/craft on line 21

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php' (include_path='.') in /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/craft on line 21

Strangely i have no /bootstrap directory under the following path xxx/vendor/craftcms/cms/..

I tried to execute composer update over ssh, but i get the same message.
I once installed craft manually on our webserver. I'm not sure if composer is installed?

Thank for helping us.

Comment: Can you try to rename or move your `vendor` folder from its current location then run `composer install` via ssh again.

Comment: I renamed the vendor folder and ran composer install . I got: Warning: require_once(/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/craft on line 12

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.') in /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/craft on line 12

Comment: I had to try to get it running again...i've seen that many folders in /vendor/craftcms/cms were missing. So i replaced them and could finally finish the update over the CLI. But now i've got a "internal server error" and my knowledge is at its end.